# Permutation of predictor in random forest

Tags: random-forest

I have a simple question on how the permutation of a predictor is done in calculating importance of a predictor in Random Forest. As per my understanding, I have a OOB sample of size 100 and a predictor p1 which is allowed to take only 5 values (1,2,3,4,5). Then I have 100^5 possible permutations of p1? The process is repeated across all other predictors with the other predictors held constant and then averaged?

Comment: The default is to permute the variable once and calculate the new performance with the permuted variable. The difference of performance (e.g. error rate) is your RF importance. See here for a detailed explanation: https://www.statistik.uni-dortmund.de/useR-2008/slides/Strobl+Zeileis.pdf